# WYSIWYG web page editor

Tags: webapp-rec, html

Is there a WYSIWYG HTML editor that can speed up web page creation, and generate clean, hand-editable HTML with div based layouts?

either Web or Desktop app will do

Answer (score 3):

Try [Amaya](http://www.w3.org/Amaya/). It's a desktop WYSIWYG editor much like DreamWeaver but it's free and open source.

If you want a web-based one, you might want to check out [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/). You could check its feature list [here](http://ckeditor.com/end-user-features).

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [Bluefish](http://bluefish.openoffice.nl/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

A great web based WYSIWYG editor is [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/). It's used by WordPress and has tonnes of features and there are quite a few plugins available for it.